# What Data Types does PowerShell have?

Tags: powershell

I searched on Stack Overflow and Google but couldn't find an answer to my question:
Which data types (e.g. `string`, `XML`, `regex`, `int` etc.) does PowerShell have? There seems to be no list on Microsoft TechNet and I found no way to simply list them all.

Comment: .NET have them, PowerShell just use them.

Comment: Have a look at the following link, you will find a list in the bottom of the page: https://4sysops.com/archives/the-powershell-variable-naming-value-data-type/#data-type

Comment: You can use everything that .Net offer. Otherwise just read the tutorials you will understand how easy it is to use.

Comment: Thanks for yours answers but how can i get a list of all data types? The posted link to the list is sadly incomplete.
Thanks @Nordes but i read a lot of tutorials and know how the use them. This is why i'm so curious to find out which data types PoSh has... :)

Comment: `[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % GetExportedTypes | % FullName`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As already [hinted by PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562271/what-data-types-does-powershell-have#comment66435097_39562271), the type system in PowerShell is a direct extension of the [.NET CTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e(v=vs.110).aspx) - any .NET type loaded into the AppDomain currently hosting your PowerShell environment can be used.

In .NET, types (classes, structs, enums and builtin value types) are compiled into *assemblies* (usually in the form of a `.dll` file).

If you want an exhaustive list of those, you can simply enumerate all assemblies currently loaded into memory, then enumerate all the types in said assemblies:

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |Foreach-Object {
    $_.GetExportedTypes()
}
```

If you just want a list of all the [Type Accelerators](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/08/use-powershell-to-find-powershell-type-accelerators/) (the shortname aliases like `[regex]`,`[wmi]`, `[adsi]` etc.), you can use the following trick:

```
$AcceleratorType = [psobject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$AcceleratorType::Get
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you! So i was looking for aliases (type accelerators) all the time instead of "real" types.